# How to insert data from a table to a specific column of another?

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables. Table1 have two columns, col1 and col2, where col1 is already filled. The other table, Table2, has many columns but there is 1 column, sub, that I need and I need it to fill the 2nd column in Table1.

The problem when I use

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col2) SELECT Table2.sub FROM Table2
```

is that, yes, it copies the content of the required column to Table1 but it creates a new row for each.

Table1 looks like:

```
+-----+------+
|col1 | col2 |
+-----+------+
|data | NULL | 
+-----+------+
|data2| Null |
+-----+------+
```

After doing the INSERT query above, I get:

```
+-----+------+
|col1 | col2 |
+-----+------+
|data | NULL | 
+-----+------+
|data2| Null |
+-----+------+
|Null | data4|
+-----+------+
|Null | data5|
+-----+------+
```

What I need to look like is:

```
+-----+-------+
|col1 | col2  |
+-----+-------+
|data | data4 | 
+-----+-------+
|data2| data5 |
+-----+-------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a relation between table1 and table2?  How do you know `data4` belongs in the row with `data`, not the row with `data2`?

Comment: Nice question. As a matter of fact, that's what I'm trying to find out because without that relation it simply creates a new row below the existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query

```
UPDATE Table1 set col2= SELECT Table2.sub FROM Table2 where Table1.col1=Table2.col1
```

OR

```
UPDATE Table1 set col2= (SELECT Table2.sub FROM Table2 where Table1.col1=Table2.col1)
```

I believe you have col1 in Table2 too as without that you can't compare two tables...

Let me know if it works....

Comment: I'm sorry... The second one with the "()" in the SELECT statement. The first one gives a syntax error.

Again, thank you! I've been trying to search for answers all night. Turned out I just had to ask the question myself. 

I needed this function so badly because I need it for a group thesis where we will allow a professor to upload grades automatically.